# Take an error when I've try apply my CA certificate to Apache Solr

Tags: ssl, https, solr

I've try to apply my CA certificate to Solr. I've already reach solr with http or self-signed certificate following their own recipe in there: [enabling ssl](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/enabling-ssl.html#EnablingSSL-CreateaSolrCloudcollectionusingbin/solr)

But, when I try to apply my CA certificate I take an error : "HTTP ERROR 404 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down."

[Full error message that I've take on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4ExZ.png)

My solr.in.sh config is:

```
SOLR_SSL_ENABLED=true
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=/etc/default/mykeystore
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=********
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=/etc/default/mykeystore
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=********
SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
# SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false
#SOLR_SSL_CLIENT_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION=true
SOLR_SSL_CHECK_PEER_NAME=false
SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=JKS
SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE=JKS
```

I followed this two link for convert my pem file to key store: first:[1](https://mkyong.com/linux/ssl-convert-pem-and-private-key-to-pkcs12/) then:[2](https://jackstromberg.com/2013/05/importing-a-ssl-certificate-into-a-java-keystore-via-a-pkcs12-file/) (I applied just fourth step in second link) then named the file as mykeystore.

I tried a lot of solution which some of them in stackoverflow. But none of them are my answer. Any help, any idea can be very useful. I'm totally stuck. What can I do/check?

Comment: If you look further down in the log you should be able to see what the original exception that causes the core to not be loaded is.

Comment: HTTP ERROR 404 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.

Comment: That's the same error message you included in your question. You need to either include the complete startup log or at least move further down the log to see what the originating exception is. The "not initialized or shutting down" message is just the end result, not the cause.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I checked Solr.log file. "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error instantiating shardHandlerFactory class [HttpShardHandlerFactory]: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: X509ExtendedKeyManager only supported on Server"

Comment: Seems to be related to multiple certificates being present in your keyfile; when used with the internal client to make requests to other Solr nodes, it can only contain a single certificate - I'm guessing this might be the issue. See https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4425 for details about the error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is my SolR's version. It seems that enabling SSL on versions older than 8.11.1 is causing problems. I upgraded the version to 8.11.1 and the problem was solved.